# Reading file and then counting the lines in said file

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program where the program asks the user for a file. The program then should then print the contents of the file and then count the lines. The issue when I run the program is I get this error: `for count in range[1, f2_l + 1]:TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`. Isn't the count supposed to be an integer and not a string? I'd like to use keep using `while f2_l != '':`.

```
f1 = input('Please enter filename you wish to open.: ')   
f2 = open(f1, 'r') 
f2_l = f2.readline()
for count in range[1, f2_l + 1]:
    print(count,':')
while f2_l != '':
    print(f2_l)
    f2_l = f2.readline()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Change `readline()` for `readlines()`. `readline()` return a str, `readlines()` a list

Comment: I made the change suggested and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Function arguments go in parentheses, not square brackets.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `f2_l + 1`? `f2_l` is the first line of the file, not a number, you can't add 1 to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = input('Please enter filename you wish to open.: ')   
f2 = open(f1, 'r') 
f2_l = f2.readlines()
for i in range(1, len(f2_l)):
    print(i, ':', f2_l[i - 1])
f2.close()
```

Read the docs for file manipulation and loops. i is the index in the line list. `readlines()` return the list of lines, each one is an str

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this:

```
filename = input('Please enter filename you wish to open.: ')

with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for index, line in enumerate(data, 1):
    print('{index}: {line}'.format(index=index, line=line))
```

It is better to do the following:

1. Open files with the `with` statement, which ensures that the files you open will be closed;
2. Use the built-in function `enumerate` rather than a separate for loop for the index
3. Instead of concatenating strings with `+`, use the `format` method

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's built-in [`enunerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function as shown below to count the lines semi-automatically as they're printed:

```
filename = input('Please enter filename you wish to open: ')
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    count = 0  # In case file is empty.
    for count, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        print(line, end='')

print('line count:', count)
```